# I want to test my app in itunesconnect my app status is "Pending Developer Release"

Tags: iphone, app-store, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

Is it possible to test the app with this status "Pending Developer Release" to test flight. Before moving to app store i need to test my app.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about the App Store review process are [off-topic](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic). We can't answer these types of questions reliably as we don't know the internal processes of accepting and rejecting apps.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns the policies and procedures of app distribution services, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?‍](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165), [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?(https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually yes there is an old tip !
Go to you app page on itunes Connect and at the bottom of the page click the `Promo Codes` link.

Generate a link and use it in the App Store Application at the very bottom of the first page. 
I am on the French store but in English it should be something like `use a code`or `redeem`.

Enter your code and it will download the Pending Developer Release build

Nicolas